# C++ Array call-by-reference with template

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to use call-by-reference with an array and found something on here which seemed to solve my problem. However I now changed it to this and I get the error message

"template argument deduction/substitution failed".

It works if I put

```
bool a[3];
```

but not with the variable m.

```
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T, int Size>
void dosth(T (&a)[Size])
{
    assert(Size > 2);

    a[2] = false;
}

int main()
{
    int m=3;
    bool a[m];
    dosth(a);
}
```

Comment: You should state your error message rather than "it doesn't work".

Comment: The `bool a[m];` is known as a *variable length array* and not supported in C++.  However, if you were to use `const unsigned int` for the capacity or `#define` for the capacity, it would be an array in local storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bool a[m]; is known as a variable length array and not supported in C++.

However, if you were to use `const unsigned int` for the capacity or `#define` for the capacity, it would be an array in local storage.

If you want an array whose length is determined at run-time, consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: This is a known issue with VLAs. Their current implementation (from what I have read elsewhere) is crufted-in such that they will break with things like this.

Comment: Thanks, I think this answers my question. This is just the first time I am using C++ and I'm used to working with array from Java. I'll consider using `std::vector` next time. Maybe I'll try it with `const unsigned int`.